# Error trying to add navigation to app

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I'm using [react native off canvas menu](https://github.com/shoumma/react-native-off-canvas-menu) and redux.

I now need to navigate programmatically which I don't think react native off canvas menu allows so I need to bring in the simplest navigation system I can find to add to my app.

I'm trying to add [react native redux router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-redux-router) and I'm getting the error:

> mapStateToProps() in Connect(Router) must return a plain object.
>   Instead received undefined.

code:

this is really my base component. It only used to contain `<Menu/>` but I added a `Router` to it:

**Vepo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { fetchCategories } from './categories/categories.action'
import { getCurrentPosition } from './location/location.action'
import Menu from './menu/Menu'
import { View } from 'react-native'

import AddPage from './add-page/AddPage'
import SearchPage from './search-page/SearchPage'



var { Router, Route } = require('react-native-redux-router')

class Vepo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
    store.dispatch(getCurrentPosition())
    store.dispatch(fetchCategories())
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render() {
    console.log('vepo')
    return (
      <View>
        <Menu />
        <Router>
          <Route name="add" component={AddPage} />
          <Route name="search" component={SearchPage} />
        </Router>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
Vepo.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Vepo
```

and that gets created here:

**index.js**

```
//@flow
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Vepo from './components/Vepo'
import keyword from './components/search-page/keywords.reducer'
import categories from './components/categories/categories.reducer'
import { location } from './components/location/location.reducer'
import distanceFromPlaceValue from
  './components/distanceSlider/distanceSlider.reducer'
import searchPage from './components/search-page/searchPage.reducer'
import {
  fetchProductsEpic,
  fetchProductsFulfilledEpic
} from './components/search-page/searchPage.epic'
import addPage from './components/add-page/addPage.reducer'
import productDetails from './components/add-page/addForm.reducer'
import alertModal from './components/alert-modal/alertModal.reducer'
import map from './components/map/map.reducer'
import menu from './components/menu/menu.reducer'
import initialState from './config/config'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools'
import React from 'react'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
import fetchCategoriesEpic from './components/categories/categories.epic'
import {
  getCurrentLocationEpic,
  getCurrentPositionEpic,
  getAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getPlaceDetailsEpic
} from './components/location/location.epic'
import {
  getShopAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getShopPlaceDetailsEpic
} from './components/shop/shop.epic'
import {
  uploadImageEpic,
  uploadProductEpic,
  uploadImageFulfilledEpic,
  uploadImageRejectedEpic,
  uploadProductFulfilledEpic,
  uploadProductRejectedEpic
} from './components/add-page/addForm.epic'
import { shop } from './components/shop/shop.reducer'
import searchResults from './components/search-results/searchResults.reducer'
import searchResultsPresenter from './components/search-results/searchResultsPresenter.reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
  {
    searchForm: combineReducers(
      {
        keyword,
        categories,
        location,
        distanceFromPlaceValue
      }),
    searchPage,
    addPage,
    addForm: combineReducers({
      productDetails,
      shop
    }),
    map,
    searchResults,
    searchResultsPresenter,
    menu,
    alertModal,
  }
)

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  fetchCategoriesEpic,
  uploadImageEpic,
  uploadProductEpic,
  uploadImageFulfilledEpic,
  uploadImageRejectedEpic,
  getCurrentLocationEpic,
  fetchProductsFulfilledEpic,
  getCurrentPositionEpic,
  getShopAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getShopPlaceDetailsEpic,
  getAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  fetchProductsEpic,
  getPlaceDetailsEpic,
  uploadProductFulfilledEpic,
  uploadProductRejectedEpic
)

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic))
  )
)

export const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Vepo />
  </Provider>
)
```

And this is the component where I want to programmatically navigate from (search for `Actions.add()`):

**Menu.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { closePageMenu, openPageMenu } from './menu.action'
import { OffCanvasReveal } from 'react-native-off-canvas-menu'
import AddPage from '../add-page/AddPage'
import SearchPage from '../search-page/SearchPage'
import AlertModal  from '../alert-modal/AlertModal'
import {
  updateAlertModalIsOpen
} from '../alert-modal/alertModal.action'
var { Actions } = require('react-native-redux-router')

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isOpen: state.get('menu').get('isOpen')
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateAlertModalIsOpen: (isOpen) => {
    dispatch(updateAlertModalIsOpen(isOpen))
  },
  closePageMenu: () => {
    console.log("you must have closed the menu")
    dispatch(closePageMenu())
  },
  openPageMenu: () => {
    console.log("you must have opened the menu")
    dispatch(openPageMenu())
  }
})

let Menu = (props) => {
  console.log('menu')
  return(
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    <AlertModal yesClicked={() => {
      Actions.add()
      console.log("yes clicked")
      props.updateAlertModalIsOpen(false)
    }} />
    <OffCanvasReveal
      active={props.isOpen}
      onMenuPress={props.closePageMenu}
      backgroundColor={'#222222'}
      menuTextStyles={{ 
        color: '#FFFFFF', backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      }}
      handleBackPress={true}
      menuItems={[
        {
          title: 'Search Products',
          icon: <Icon 
            name="search" 
            size={35} 
            color={'#FFFFFF'} />,
          renderScene: <SearchPage />
        },
        {
          title: 'Add Products',
          icon: <Icon 
            name="plus" 
            size={35}
            color={'#FFFFFF'} />,
          renderScene: <AddPage rerenderKey={false} />
        }
      ]} />
  </View>
)}
Menu.propTypes = {
  closePageMenu: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isOpen: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  updateAlertModalIsOpen: React.PropTypes.func
}

Menu = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Menu)

export default Menu
```

Why am I getting the error? Is there a simpler way to navigate given I use react native off canvas menu?

**edit. Just added routerReducer:**

```
var { routerReducer } = require('react-native-redux-router')

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
  {
    searchForm: combineReducers(
      {
        keyword,
        categories,
        location,
        distanceFromPlaceValue
      }),
    searchPage,
    addPage,
    addForm: combineReducers({
      productDetails,
      shop
    }),
    map,
    searchResults,
    searchResultsPresenter,
    menu,
    alertModal,
    routerReducer
  }
)
```

getting error same error

**EDIT: [I'm now trying to use react-navigation](http://moduscreate.com/react-navigation-redux-in-react-native-applications/):**

**index.js**

```
//@flow
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import Vepo from './components/Vepo'
import keyword from './components/search-page/keywords.reducer'
import categories from './components/categories/categories.reducer'
import { location } from './components/location/location.reducer'
import distanceFromPlaceValue from
  './components/distanceSlider/distanceSlider.reducer'
import searchPage from './components/search-page/searchPage.reducer'
import {
  fetchProductsEpic,
  fetchProductsFulfilledEpic
} from './components/search-page/searchPage.epic'
import addPage from './components/add-page/addPage.reducer'
import productDetails from './components/add-page/addForm.reducer'
import alertModal from './components/alert-modal/alertModal.reducer'
import map from './components/map/map.reducer'
import menu from './components/menu/menu.reducer'
import initialState from './config/config'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
import fetchCategoriesEpic from './components/categories/categories.epic'
import {
  getCurrentLocationEpic,
  getCurrentPositionEpic,
  getAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getPlaceDetailsEpic
} from './components/location/location.epic'
import {
  getShopAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getShopPlaceDetailsEpic
} from './components/shop/shop.epic'
import {
  uploadImageEpic,
  uploadProductEpic,
  uploadImageFulfilledEpic,
  uploadImageRejectedEpic,
  uploadProductFulfilledEpic,
  uploadProductRejectedEpic
} from './components/add-page/addForm.epic'
import { shop } from './components/shop/shop.reducer'
import searchResults from './components/search-results/searchResults.reducer'
import searchResultsPresenter from './components/search-results/searchResultsPresenter.reducer'
import { StackNavigator, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation'

import AddPage from './components/add-page/AddPage'
import SearchPage from './components/search-page/SearchPage'

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Add: { screen: AddPage },
    Search: { screen: SearchPage }
})

const navReducer = (state, action) => {
    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
    return newState || state
}

class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator
                navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                    state: this.props.nav
                })}
            />
        )
    }
}

let AppWithNavigationStateComponent = connect(state => ({
    nav: state.nav
}))(AppWithNavigationState)

export const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationStateComponent />
        </Provider>
    )
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
  {
    searchForm: combineReducers(
      {
        keyword,
        categories,
        location,
        distanceFromPlaceValue
      }),
    searchPage,
    addPage,
    addForm: combineReducers({
      productDetails,
      shop
    }),
    map,
    searchResults,
    searchResultsPresenter,
    menu,
    alertModal,
    navReducer
  }
)

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  fetchCategoriesEpic,
  uploadImageEpic,
  uploadProductEpic,
  uploadImageFulfilledEpic,
  uploadImageRejectedEpic,
  getCurrentLocationEpic,
  fetchProductsFulfilledEpic,
  getCurrentPositionEpic,
  getShopAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getShopPlaceDetailsEpic,
  getAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  fetchProductsEpic,
  getPlaceDetailsEpic,
  uploadProductFulfilledEpic,
  uploadProductRejectedEpic
)

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic))
  )
)
```

Getting error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluation
>   this.props.navigation.state.index